# if statement that skips over a field if it has a string in it. Netsuite/ javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, netsuite

This is a Netsuite sales order. I created a loop that cycles through a list of line items and a variable that grabs the value of a certain field. I just need to create an if statement that will "continue" the script over if the field already has a string in it. Here is what I have so far. This is a portion of a larger script for context.

```
var duplicateOrder = loadRecord.getlineItemValue('custcol_transfer_order_sale', itemCounter);
      //if transfer order field is already populated then there doesn't need to be a second transfer
    if ((duplicateOrder) !== null || (duplicateOrder) !== ""){
        continue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently checking if `duplicateOrder` is empty and then continuing. If I'm understanding correctly, you'd like to `continue` when it's *not* empty.

For that, you just need to check if `duplicateOrder` is ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), like so:

```
if (duplicateOrder) {
    continue;
}
```

See also ["falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Comment: I forgot to add the ! in:                                                                                     if ((duplicateOrder) !== null || (duplicateOrder) !== ""){
        continue;                                                                                                  
}

Comment: And what is the problem you're seeing now?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot find function getlineItemValue in object nlobjRecord.

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive. The function is `getLineItemValue`, not `getlineItemValue`

Comment: You will also need to make sure you are passing in the required arguments for the call. `objRec.getLineItemValue(sublistId, fieldId, lineNumber)`.